# Generate Random number from a kernel distribution simulink

Tags: random, simulink, probability-density

I have a kernel distribution object which I can use to generate random numbers in matlab easily by using the random function. However I need to do the same now in a simulink simulation, here I'm at a loss as the different approaches I've tried have all generated an error. What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

These are what my attempts have been:
I first tried to use the from workspace block in simulink, the problem with this was that the from workspace block only imports timeseries object or structs with a specific format. kernel distribution objects are not supported.

Second attempt I've tried to use the the data memory store block but that doesn't seem to support objects either.

Comment: What about writing a small m script which generates the numbers using the object and puts them into a timeseries object?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wound up doing, I don't know why I didn't do this in the first place.